# XCode display a project image in the credits.rtf file

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nsmenuitem, nsimageview

I want to take an image from my project and add it to the "About MyApp" window.

This seemed as simple as adding the image to the credits.rtf file; once I dragged and dropped the image from the project to the credits.rtf file, it inserted the image into the file and I put it where I wanted it, but as soon as I ran the application, there was just a space where I had put the image.

Is there any way to show an image in the About MyApp menu (other than the application icon) without creating a custom NSView and changing the target of the About NSMenuItem?

Comment: Nope.  NSTextFields don't know how to display images.  Really, how hard is it to just instantiate an NSImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new Xcode project, selected it's 'Credits.rtf' file and pasted in an image, built and ran it and the image auto-magicly showed up in my "About…" dialog.

Note: it changed the file extension to '.rtfd' and I got the following dialog (sheet):

[image]